# Javascript: How to extract measurements in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract measurements in a string.

This is my current approach:

```js
const string = '10mL 5mL';
const regex = `([0-9]*mL)|([0-9]*g)|([0-9]*gallon)|([0-9]*kg)|([0-9]*L)|([0-9]*mg)|([0-9]*patches)`;
console.log(string.matches(regex));
```

So I'm expecting that the output would be `['10mL', '5mL']`. When I check the logs it only extracts the first `10mL`

```
[ '10mL',
  '10mL',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  index: 0,
  input: '10mL 5mL',
  groups: undefined ]
```

Any tips on what I am missing here? Thank you!

Comment: `matches` ....?

Comment: What @Tim did was tell it to match globally. The first forward slash and last forward slash denote the beginning and end of the regular expression... The 'g' on the end is a modifier which indicates to match globally (multiple results).

Comment: too many parentheses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `match` and not `matches`. Also you can write your regex in a compact form like this,

```
/(\d+\s*(?:mL|g|gallon|kg|L|mg|patches))/g
```

Try this JS code,

```js
const string = '10mL 5mL 25 mL';
const regex = /(\d+\s*(?:mL|g|gallon|kg|L|mg|patches))/g;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Sure Timothy Hawkins, you can replace `\d+` with `\d+(\.\d+)?` in the regex and it would capture decimal numbers too.

Demo is following,

```js
const string = '10mL 5mL 25 mL 12.5kg, 5.2mL';
const regex = /(\d+(\.\d+)?\s*(?:mL|g|gallon|kg|L|mg|patches))/g;
console.log(string.match(regex));
```

Sorry for the delay in replying, not mostly active as loaded with too much work :(

Comment: Thanks for simplifying! Appreciate the help

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Comment: If i wanted to also get the match for a measurement with this format "5 mL", how do I go with the optional "spaces"?

Comment: Will have to just introduce `\s*` after `\d+` which will allow it to have zero or more whitespaces in between and the regex becomes `(\d+\s*(?:mL|g|gallon|kg|L|mg|patches))` Let me update this in my answer as well.

Comment: Great answer Pushpesh! Would it be possible to update the regex to match decimals in the string as well? eg. 12.5kg, 5.2mL. Currently it returns 5kg, 2mL for these

Answer (score 3):

Try matching the regex pattern `\d+\s*\w+` multiple times:

```js
var re = /\d+\s*\w+/g;
var input = '10mL 5mL';
var m;
var output = [];

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
       output.push(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Oh. Now that I noticed your code, a regex is not a "string" perse. Damn! Thanks for the illumination.

Comment: @Jhn There are a few ways to phrase a regex in JavaScript.  You don't have to use `RegExp` if you don't want to; and not using means slightly simpler syntax.